# iOS5 - Does the ActiveSync Pin code lock prevent the new camera shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, camera, ios, exchange-activesync

I've had an iPhone of various vintages for 3 years connected to MS Exchange activesync for work email.

Part of the deal with this that you need to enter a four digit PIN before you unlock.

I was quite excited about the iOS5 camera option available from the lock screen.

From what I can see - the camera shortcut is not available if you have ActiveSync enabled and thus the four digit PIN. I'm asking the question because I hope I am wrong. Here is my question:

Does the ActiveSync Pin code lock prevent the new camera shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the PIN Code doesn't prevent you from using the camera shortcut.

Just make sure to **double-press** the home button to show the camera shortcut.

Note: you can't access your old photos as long as the iPhone is locked.